# Filter object based on attribute within an nth deep nested object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, recursion, filter, tree

I have a tree which will which vary in the amount of nested objects it may contain. A generalized example looks like -

```
const treeData = {
    id: 1,
    title: "Group1",
    tagClass: "Object",
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Group2",
            tagClass: "Object",
            children: [
                { id: 3, title: "Tag1", tagClass: "Variable" },
                { id: 4, title: "Tag2", tagClass: "Variable" },
            ],
        },
        { id: 5, title: "Group3", tagClass: "Object" },
        { id: 6, title: "Tag3", tagClass: "Variable" },
    ],
};
```

I'm trying to remove all nested objects which have `tagClass: Variable` as a property, and then leave a reference of that object's ID in an array as an attribute in its parent object -

```
const treeData = {
    id: 1,
    title: "Group1",
    tagClass: "Object",
    tagIds: [6]
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Group2",
            tagClass: "Object",
            tagIds: [3,4]
        },
        { id: 5, title: "Group3", tagClass: "Object" },
    ],
};
```

I know that .filter, .map, and recursion will be handy tools for this but I am coming up short and nearing wits end. Any help to solve this algorithmic problem is very much appreciated. Part of what I've tried -

```
const recursiveFunc = (treeData) => {
    if (treeData.children) {
        treeData.children = treeData.children
            .filter((child) => child.tagClass === "Object")
            .map((child) => recursiveFunc(child));
        return treeData;
    }
};

const updatedTreeData = recursiveFunc(treeData);
```

Thank you to the intelligent mind who can help to solve this. Cheers.

Comment: *"...and then leave a reference of that object's ID in an array as an attribute in its parent object."* Huh?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess he meant `tagIds: [3,4]` from the second code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recursiveFunc` method based on your idea. create `tagIds` property during filter. Please see comment in code snippet for details.

```js
const treeData = {
    id: 1,
    title: "Group1",
    tagClass: "Object",
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Group2",
            tagClass: "Object",
            children: [
                { id: 3, title: "Tag1", tagClass: "Variable" },
                { id: 4, title: "Tag2", tagClass: "Variable" },
            ],
        },
        { id: 5, title: "Group3", tagClass: "Object" },
        { id: 6, title: "Tag3", tagClass: "Variable" },
    ],
};

const recursiveFunc = (treeData) => {
  if(treeData.children){
     //filter treeData.children
     const children = treeData.children.filter(child => {
      if(child.tagClass === 'Variable'){
        //if tagclass is variable we create tagIds property for treeData
        treeData.tagIds? treeData.tagIds.push(child.id) : treeData.tagIds = [child.id];
        // return false to filter out this child
        return false
      }
      //not varaible tagclass, we go deeper
      recursiveFunc(child);
      //keep the child
      return true
    })
    //if children is an empty array, delete children property from treeData
    children.length === 0 ? delete treeData.children : treeData.children = children
  }
  return treeData
};

const updatedTreeData = recursiveFunc(treeData);

console.log(updatedTreeData)
```

Comment: This works and the comments help a ton. The other answers give very creative and graceful solutions but for the intermediate developer that I am, this remains the most readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**recursive data are for recursive programs are for recursive data**

You can write a recursive `transform` function using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). `transform` takes an input, `o`, and a function `test` that receives an object and returns `true` if (and only if) the object should be transformed.

1. If the input, `o`, is an array, `transform` each child, `v`, with the same `test`
2. Inductive reasoning says the input, `o`, is *not* an array. If the input is an object and it passes the `test`, prune this object and return only a reference to the input's `id`
3. Inductive reasoning says the input, `o`, is an object and does *not* pass the `test`. Map over the input object and `transform` each child value, `v`, with the same `test`
4. Inductive reasoning says the input, `o`, is *not* an array and *not* an object. The input is a simple value, such as a string `"foo"` or a number `1`. Return the input un-`transform`-ed.

```js
const transform = (o = {}, test = identity) =>
  Array.isArray(o)
    ? o.map(v => transform(v, test))          // 1
  : Object(o) === o
    ? test(o)
      ? o.id                                  // 2
      : objectMap(o, v => transform(v, test)) // 3
  : o                                         // 4
```

Offloading the work to `objectMap` function makes it easier for us to solve our problem and promotes code reuse through use of generic procedures -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const objectMap = (o = {}, f = identity) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, f(v) ])
  )
  
const example =
  objectMap
    ( { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
    , x => x * x                // <-- square each value
    )

console.log(example)
// { a: 1, b: 4, c: 9, d: 16 }  // <-- squared
```

We use `transform` like a higher-order function, such as `.filter` -

```js
const result =
  transform
    ( treeData   // <-- input
    , x => x.tagClass === "Variable" // <-- test
    )

console.log(result)
```

Output -

```js
{ id: 1
, title: "Group1"
, tagClass: "Object"
, children:
  [ { id: 2
    , title: "Group2"
    , tagClass: "Object"
    , children: [ 3, 4 ] // <-- transformed 3 and 4
    }
  , { id: 5
    , title: "Group3"
    , tagClass: "Object"
    }
  , 6  // <-- transformed 6
  ]
}
```

---

**code sandbox**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const objectMap = (o = {}, f = identity) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, f(v) ])
  )

const transform = (o = {}, test = identity) =>
  Array.isArray(o)
    ? o.map(v => transform(v, test))
  : Object(o) === o
    ? test(o)
      ? o.id
      : objectMap(o, v => transform(v, test))
  : o

const treeData =
  {id:1,title:"Group1",tagClass:"Object",children:[{id:2,title:"Group2",tagClass:"Object",children:[{id:3,title:"Tag1",tagClass:"Variable"},{id:4,title:"Tag2",tagClass:"Variable"}]},{id:5,title:"Group3",tagClass:"Object"},{id:6,title:"Tag3",tagClass:"Variable"}]}

const result =
  transform
    ( treeData
    , ({ tagClass = "" }) => tagClass === "Variable"
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

---

**improving readability**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using recursion with functional style yields the best results. Functional programming is all about reducing complexity and reusing well-defined generic functions. I think the following abstractions make `transform` even better -

```js
const isArray =
  Array.isArray

const isObject = o =>
  Object(o) === o

const transform = (o = {}, test = identity) =>
  isArray(o)
    ? o.map(v => transform(v, test))        // 1
  : isObject(o) && test(o)
    ? o.id                                  // 2
  : isObject(o)
    ? objectMap(o, v => transform(v, test)) // 3
  : o                                       // 4

const result =
  transform
    ( treeData
    , ({ tagClass = "" }) =>
        tagClass === "Variable"
    )

console.log(result)
```

---

**what the program *doesn't* do**

1. mutate the input or have other side effects
2. make assumptions about `children` or `tagIds`
3. unnecessarily check the `length` of arrays

Which should make that `o.id` feel a little out of place. What if we wanted to shape the results differently in different scenarios? Why should the `id` transformation be set in stone?

By defining another functional parameter, `prune` ...

```js
const transform = (o = {}, test = identity, prune = identity) =>
  isArray(o)
    ? o.map(v => transform(v, test, prune))    // <-- pass prune
  : isObject(o) && test(o)
    ? prune(o)                                 // <-- prune!
  : isObject(o)
    ? objectMap(o, v => transform(v, test, prune)) // <-- pass prune
  : o
```

Now we can define how `transform` runs the `test` and performs the `prune` at the call site -

```
const result =
  transform
    ( treeData
    , ({ tagClass = "" }) =>     
        tagClass === "Variable"   // <-- test
    , ({ id = 0, title = "" }) => 
        ({ id, title })           // <-- return only { id, title }
    )
```

Output -

```js
{ id: 1
, title: "Group1"
, tagClass: "Object"
, children:
  [ { id: 2
    , title: "Group2"
    , tagClass: "Object"
    , children:
        [ { id: 3, title: "Tag1" } // <--  prune { id, title }
        , { id: 4, title: "Tag2" } // <-- prune { id, title }
        ]
    }
  , { id: 5
    , title: "Group3"
    , tagClass: "Object"
    }
  , { id: 6, title: "Tag3" } // <-- prune { id, title }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As always, a well-written and informative answer.  But note that the output doesn't quite match the OP's request, which wanted to collect the *Variables* into an array of ids, under the property `tagIds`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'm guilty of bending the question when I sense a code smell. It's hard to provide perfect advice because we don't know how the transformed result will actually be used.

Comment: This had got to be the most informative response I have ever received on SO. Lots to take in. I am going to reference this at work this week. 

If you wrote a book, I would be apt to read it. I didn't think this code smelled, but now I can understand why it does.

Comment: @Sean: You might find it informative to read other answer by Thankyou.  Those answers are most often like this one: incredibly detailed, incredibly informative, and instructional in ways rarely seen in an open forum like StackOverflow.  I've learned a lot from them over the last few years.

Comment: @Thankyou: Of course.  The best questions offer some room for a variety of answers, including solutions that veer from the request to offer something potentially more useful.  I would not have pointed it out if it was clear that you did so intentionally.  But I may have missed it; I must admit to only skimming your answer, having recently answered several questions with a similar `deepMap` function.

Comment: I'm delighted to contribute. Feel free to reach out if you have specific questions :)

Answer (score 2):

This would be my approach:

```js
const transform = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  const kids = (children || []) .filter (({tagClass}) => tagClass !== 'Variable')
  const tags = (children || []) .filter (({tagClass}) => tagClass === 'Variable')

  return {
    ... rest,
    ... (tags .length ? {tagIds: tags .map (({id}) => id)} : {}),
    ... (kids .length ? {children: kids .map (transform)} : {})
  }
}

const treeData = {id: 1, title: "Group1", tagClass: "Object", children: [{id: 2, title: "Group2", tagClass: "Object", children: [{id: 3, title: "Tag1", tagClass: "Variable"}, {id: 4, title: "Tag2", tagClass: "Variable"}]}, {id: 5, title: "Group3", tagClass: "Object"}, {id: 6, title: "Tag3", tagClass: "Variable"}]}

console .log (
  transform (treeData)
)
```

We separate out `Variables` from the others, collect the `id` properties of the variables into `tagIds` and then recur on the remaining children.  This might be improved by a `partition` function that allowed

```
const [tags, kids] = 
  partition (({tagClass}) => tagClass === 'Variable')) (children)
```

but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: loving the dense use of spreads here, almost looks like a pseudocode but it's real JS!

Comment: Thank you Scott. I would've never thought to solve this problem the way in which you provided above. It is a very short and sweet solution, but I feel as though my lack of expertise makes it a bit hard to grasp at first, with the 'dense' use of spreads. I truly look forward to the day I am able to think like you, from a technical point of view.

Comment: @Thankyou: I have felt like that about various ES6+ features since they were unlikely proposals.  Arrow functions, rest/spread, and several other features have made for much more expressive code.

Comment: @Sean: this is so heavily invested in rest/spread syntax mostly because your requested output did not include empty `tagId`s or `children`.  If it wouldn't bother you to have empty arrays for those nodes, we could replace `... (tags .length ? {tagIds: tags .map (({id}) => id)} : {}),` with simply `tagIds: tags .map (({id}) => id)` and something similar for `children`.  And note that the non-`rest` instances are not essential.  They could just as easily have been written with `Object.assign`.

Finally, I've been doing JS since 1998.  This style did not come to me overnight!  Keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an in-place version using recursion. You can pass the parent into the recursive call or return to the parent whether the child should be kept in the `children` array or not and re-arranging the parent accordingly.

```js
const moveVarIdToParent = root => {
  if (root.children) {
    const children = root.children.map(e => [e, moveVarIdToParent(e)]);
    root.tagIds = children.filter(e => e[1]).map(e => e[0].id);
    root.children = children.filter(e => !e[1]).map(e => e[0]);

    if (!root.children.length) {
      delete root.children;
    }

    if (!root.tagIds.length) {
      delete root.tagIds;
    }
  }

  return root.tagClass === "Variable";
};

const treeData = {
    id: 1,
    title: "Group1",
    tagClass: "Object",
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Group2",
            tagClass: "Object",
            children: [
                { id: 3, title: "Tag1", tagClass: "Variable" },
                { id: 4, title: "Tag2", tagClass: "Variable" },
            ],
        },
        { id: 5, title: "Group3", tagClass: "Object" },
        { id: 6, title: "Tag3", tagClass: "Variable" },
    ],
};

moveVarIdToParent(treeData);
console.log(treeData);
```

Comment: And yet another unique way to solve this. This works. Thank you for the approach. I have clearly been bested by a more brilliant mind, which I was hoping would happen. Cheers!